# How to come up with the equation of a line connecting two complex points?

Tags: complex-numbers

If we have a square with the vertices at the points $0,1,1+i,$ and $i$, how can we come up with equations to represent these lines?

For example what is the equation of the line connecting $1+i$ and $i$?
(I believe it is $z=(1-x)+i$ but not sure how to come up with that.

Comment: Be aware that your question may easily be misconstrued. The complex "plane" is 1-dimensional when considered as a vector space over the complex numbers, and may rightly be called a line; it's only a "plane" when we imagine it as a vector space over the reals. It sounds like you want "lines" in the real sense (parametrized by a single real number).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

An equation for a segment that joints two points $z$ and $w$ in the complex plane is $$\ell(t)=(1-t)z+tw$$
where $t\in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done parametrically. For example, the line segment from $1$ to $1+i$ is $\gamma(t)=1+it$ for $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: thank you,how did you come up with that?

Answer (score 0):

The straight line passing through $i$ and $1+i$ is simply $Im(z)=1$ and the line through $1$ and $1+i$ is $Re(z)=1$.

If you want a parametric equation for the segments you can write:
$$
z=x+i \qquad 0\le x\le 1
$$
and

$$
z=1+ix \qquad 0\le x\le 1
$$